# ORDER BY number and letter in one string(Access - SQL)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using this sql code to fetch some values from a table

```
SELECT tbl_Projektphasen.Bezeichnung, tbl_Projekttypen.ID_Projekttypen
FROM tbl_Projektphasen INNER JOIN tbl_Projekttypen ON tbl_Projektphasen.ID_Projektphasen = tbl_Projekttypen.moeglicheProjektphasen.Value
WHERE (((tbl_Projekttypen.ID_Projekttypen)=2))
```

This gives me the following output

```
1. Genehmigung
2. Genehmigung
3. Genehmigung
Konstruktion
Machbarkeitsanalyse
Abgesagt
4. Genehmigung
5. Genehmigung
```

So whatever I try (ASC or DESC) I can't get the desired order

```
1. Genehmigung
2. Genehmigung
3. Genehmigung
4. Genehmigung
5. Genehmigung
Abgesagt
Konstruktion
Machbarkeitsanalyse
```

After some intensive use of Google I came around the IIF command but as it might be that there will be maybe a "6. Genehmigung" in the future I can't use a custom order with fixed positions. I would need some kind of "search all strings starting with a numeric char and sort ASC and then search all strings starting with a letter and sort ASC" and here I failed ...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should cause numeric values up to 99 to be sorted first.

```
order by IIF( isnumeric( Mid(tbl_Projektphasen.Bezeichnung, 1, 1) ) or isnumeric( Mid(tbl_Projektphasen.Bezeichnung, 1, 2) ), 1, 2), tbl_Projektphasen.Bezeichnung
```

Explaination: If the first character or first two characters are numeric, give it an initial sorting value of 1 - otherwise, give it a sorting value of 2.  Then sort by the actual field in full.

Comment: awesome!!!! Works like a charm and thank you very much for the explanation. :)

just a little correction, had to rename "IFF" to "IIF" ;)

Comment: Good to hear, thanks for the update - I fixed it in the answer now too.

Answer (score 0):

Numbers sort before letters, so doesn't this work?

```
order by tbl_Projektphasen.Bezeichnung
```

Comment: Unfortunately not as this will result in the first output above.

But I figured out that the strings are coming from a "multi-valued field", maybe this is a problem.  

(Tried it with a new database and there it's working like a charm)